# Semaphore not working as expected in LAMP

Tags: php

my code is the following

```
<?php

        $semaphore_key = 2112;
        $semaphore_max = 1;
        $semaphore_permissions = 0666;
        $semaphore_autorelease = 1;
        $semaphore = sem_get($semaphore_key, $semaphore_max, $semaphore_permissions, $semaphore_autorelease);

        if(!$semaphore)
        {
                echo "Failed to get semaphore - sem_get().\n";
                exit();
        }else{
                echo "ok\n";
        }

        sem_acquire($semaphore);
        sleep(10);
        sem_release($semaphore);
?>
```

In the linux terminal, I run:

```
php semaphore.php &
```

and after 1 sec, I run

```
php semaphore.php
```

I expect the second call to the php to exit, but both print "ok" and arrive to the sleep(10), and I don't understand because the semaphore is locked by the other script running in background.

Since semaphore_max is set to 1, I expect the second call to the script to print "Failed to get semaphore - sem_get()." and terminate, but it is not happening.

echo $semaphore results in "Resource id #4", so I suppose sysvsem is working fine.

Someone could help?

Thanks

Comment: According to the docs, you should get a different id on a second call to the same key, and AFAIK it is not an error to get a semaphore for a key. You get a false only on error. I'd dig into the actual acquisition details and semaphore details for the rest of your question, but I would expect to get to the place where you can try to acquire the semaphore.

Comment: `sem_get` returns a semaphore resource, and it'll do so even if the semaphore is locked. To actually acquire the semaphore, you have to use `sem_acquire`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php

Answer (score 0):

`sem_get()` just fetches/constructs the semaphore object, it will only return `false` if perhaps there are no more resources available to create a semaphore, or if your parameters are invalid.

`sem_aquire()` is where the expected locking behaviour happens, but you have to pass `true` into the 2nd argument to not block and return `false` immediately.

So your code should be:

```
$semaphore = sem_get($semaphore_key, $semaphore_max, $semaphore_permissions, $semaphore_autorelease);

if(sem_aquire($semaphore, true) === false) { 
  echo "Failed to get semaphore - sem_get().\n";
  exit();
}else{
  echo "ok\n";
}

sleep(10);
sem_release($semaphore);
```